# Asp.net MVC Cascading Dropdownlist for Single Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, cascadingdropdown

I am trying to implement cascading dropdownlist but all the tutorials are for 2 or more relational tables. I have a model as below, and there is no limit for subcategory(in my model it is WhStockCardGroup) level.

When user select the main WhStockCardGroup (from first level of my tree), i need to create a new dropdownlist in the same page and fill it with the related sub categories and so on.

I have looked at some tutorials like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258172/Simple-Implementation-of-MVC-Cascading-Ajax-Drop-D but could not create a new dropdown and fill it with sub-categories.

```
 public class WhStockCardGroup
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? relatedWhStockCardGroupId { get; set; }
        public virtual WhStockCardGroup relatedWhStockCardGroup { get; set; }


        public Boolean LastChild { get; set; }
        public Boolean FirstChild { get; set; }
    }
```